# getting the error `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant I18n (NameError) while running the rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I pulled the latest code, and did bundle install. After that when i start the server I am getting the following error.

```
prashanth@prashanth-OptiPlex-390:~/proj/ysignup$ rails s
/home/prashanth/.gems/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/i18n.rb:13:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant I18n (NameError)
    from /home/prashanth/.gems/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/inflector/inflections.rb:3:in `require'
    from /home/prashanth/.gems/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/inflector/inflections.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/prashanth/.gems/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/inflections.rb:1:in `require'
    from /home/prashanth/.gems/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/inflections.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/prashanth/.gems/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:3:in `require'
    from /home/prashanth/.gems/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/prashanth/.gems/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies/autoload.rb:1:in `require'
    from /home/prashanth/.gems/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies/autoload.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/prashanth/.gems/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support.rb:25:in `require'
    from /home/prashanth/.gems/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/prashanth/.gems/gems/actionpack-4.2.10/lib/action_dispatch.rb:24:in `require'
    from /home/prashanth/.gems/gems/actionpack-4.2.10/lib/action_dispatch.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/prashanth/.gems/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:3:in `require'
    from /home/prashanth/.gems/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/prashanth/.gems/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:123:in `require'
    from /home/prashanth/.gems/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:123:in `require_command!'
    from /home/prashanth/.gems/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:73:in `server'
    from /home/prashanth/.gems/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /home/prashanth/.gems/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
prashanth@prashanth-OptiPlex-390:~/proj/ysignup$
```

Here is the Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails-i18n'
```

Comment: please check your ruby version , if is it same then remove your Gem.lock file and run bundle install.

Comment: You might want to prefix your server command with either `bin/rails s` or `bundle exec rails s` to make sure you are loading & requiring from your Gemfile, and not some other system version of Rails you might have installed.